# PHP echo with Javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, php

Ok, Apologies because this is a kind of a repeat of some previous questions but somehow those aren't getting my any closer to an answer. I have a while loop in PHP where I'm trying to update the contents of a div using Java script and I think I must be messing up the syntax somehow because I'm not getting any output. Here's the code:

```
 echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = "' . $num . ' files processed.";</script>';
```

Am I missing something here syntax wise? I feel like I must be because I can echo out just $num and get the correct values. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you *viewing the source*? A `<script>` tag doesn't result in any *rendered output*.

Comment: You also want to make sure the element `information` actually exists in the DOM first before trying to modify it. If you have this script at the top of your page, it's likely not ready in time.

Comment: Don't concatenate data directly into JavaScript, use `json_encode()` which is compatible with JS.  Don't echo a new script tag every time, there is no reason for that.  It looks like you're trying to update something as you go... and for that you're going about this all wrong.  Use AJAX or something so that the page client-side is actually there and can get the status information from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from javascript side. Just write a simple script in your php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var num = <?php echo $num ?>;

    document.getElementById("information").innerText = num + "file proceed";
</script>
```

Comment: When writing code to pass data between layers, you should always do it transparently.  Use `json_encode()` in your PHP block.  Perhaps some day `$num` is something else that you don't expect it to be today.  Also, if you're not setting HTML then don't use `innerHTML`.  Assign a text value instead.

Answer (score 0):

The output is likely cached on the server side. Use `flush()` after each echo, turn off any output buffering, gzip compression in webserver. You might also try to output white characters to fill the buffers. And inspect what you get in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `/` in `</script>`.

```
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = "' . $num . ' files processed.";<\/script>';
```